# How to know that ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory is completed

Tags: c#, async-await

I am using this method to extract a zip file.

ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory

Is there any way available that all the files are successfully extracted?

```
public async void SpinAndDisableButton()
    {
console.log("started");

            await ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, startPath);

console.log("Completed");
    }
```

but completed log is appearing before the all files extraction.

Comment: Your method is `async void` -- there's no way for a caller to know when it's finished doing asynchronous things. Make sure you return a `Task` (`async Task SpinAndDisableButton()`), then the caller can `await` that `Task` to see when your ZipFile operation is done.

Comment: That said, your question is confused. The first bit says you're using `ExtractToDirectory`, then the code uses `CreateFromDirectory`. Neither of those is returns a `Task`, so you can't `await` either. Please make sure the code in your question is correct.

Comment: How you don't get a *can't await void compiler error* with the code shown above?

Answer (score 0):

`ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` is a regular, sync function, so you can do something like:

```
await Task.Run(() => ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(startPath, zipPath));
```

Comment: yeah i thought the same that it is a sync function but why my next code is running before all files extraction?